# Caching the vendors bundle file in a multi-page app

Tags: javascript, webpack, browser-cache

Our situation is peculiar: we have Golang templates, which have a mixture of server-rendered HTML and assets for the front-end (HTML/CSS/JS tags). We're moving away from `<script>` tags everywhere and jQuery, and towards ReactJS and Webpack managing the assets.

**Template**

A typical template in our project looks something like :

```
{{/* some Golang template logic */}}


<link rel=stylesheet href="/static/css/[some-folder-or-folders]/[css-file].css">
<script src="/static/js/ViewModelViews/[some-folder-or-folders]/bundle.js"></script>
{{end}}
```

**Webpack config**

Our webpack config, as of yesterday, when I split out the `node_modules` from all the bundle files, is like this:

```
module.exports = {
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  entry: entryObj,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `./static/js`),
    filename: '[name]/bundle.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }

    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new NodemonPlugin(),
  ]

}
```

I was able to split out all the `node_modules` into `vendors/bundle.js`, but for some reason, I cannot get the browser to cache it.

I explicitly include that file, like this on the `base.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  <!-- some irrelevant logic -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- a bunch of irrelevant logic -->
    <script src="/static/js/vendors/bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- other global bundle files -->
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the `vendors/bundle.js` to cache, while still being in control of how we use the other bundle files? I see people using hashcodes in the filenames, which would break our imports of our business logic.

**Network section of Dev Tools**

When I go to landing page, there is browser request for the `vendors/bundle.js`:

[image]

The request happens again, when I go to another page!

[image]

Comment: **UPDATE** : Turns out that I had cache disabled when Dev Tools is open.

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue. As a sidenote, when the transition "towards ReactJS and Webpack managing the assets" is complete, you can use hashcodes in the script bundle names and let webpack generate .html files with references to those bundles.